# Kubernetes StatefulSets - run pod on every worker node

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling, statefulset

What is the easiest way to run a single Pod on every available worker node as part of the StatefulSet. So, a one to one mapping.

Am I right to say every Pod will run on a different Node by default with a StatefulSet? In which case is it sufficient to add x pods to the SS where x Worker nodes exist in the cluster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) instead.

> A DaemonSet ensures that all (or some) Nodes run a copy of a Pod. As nodes are added to the cluster, Pods are added to them. As nodes are removed from the cluster, those Pods are garbage collected. Deleting a DaemonSet will clean up the Pods it created.

If you really want to use statefulSet, you can take a look at features like [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) or [Affinity and Anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity).